# Is there an IRC server/client that supports integration with Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, irc, instant-messaging

I want to create an IRC server (or some other chat server) for our developers to be able to communicate in a chat room style environment. After doing some searching, I haven't found any solution that provides these abilities:

1. User's nick is set from Active Directory
2. Configure room access based on AD Groups/Roles
3. Allow users to be able to select rooms they have access to

Does anyone have any suggestions on a solution to this?

Comment: IRC with LDAP authentication maybe? You can query Active Directory with LDAP. I did a quick search on Google but nothing really stood out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [InspIRCd](http://www.inspircd.org/) will run on Win32 and has some LDAP integration functionality. The user can authenticate and get their nick from the LDAP directory (and can be disallowed from changing it after authentication) via the [ldapauth](http://wiki.inspircd.org/Modules/ldapauth) module. I suspect that integration permissions to group memberships is going to be a bit tougher and I'm not seeing anything in the documentation (albeit I'm glancing quickly) that leads me to believe that you're going to have that functionality.

I can't remember if the old Microsoft IRC server that came with Exchange 2000 would support the kinds of features you're looking for. You're never going to find it, anyway, so there's probably no point in researching it. (Yeah, Microsoft made an IRC server and shipped it with Exchange...)

Comment: wasn't that the news server? I'll look it up.

Comment: @Vick Vega: There was actually an IRC server. You can read about it a bit here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750120.aspx  It actually sounds like it would do exactly what the OP is looking for except that it hasn't been maintained for 10 years... >smile<